# A question about the Knaster-Kuratowski fan

Tags: general-topology

Is the Knaster-Kuratowski fan a Borel subset of the Euclidean plane?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. I’ll use the notation of the [Wikipedia description](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knaster%E2%80%93Kuratowski_fan) of the fan. Let $Y$ be the fan, and let $E$ be the set of endpoints of the deleted intervals. The set $\bigcup_{x\in C}L(x)$ is a compact subset of the plane, so it’s a $G_\delta$. Each $L(x)$ for $x\in E$ is closed, so $\bigcup_{x\in C\setminus E}L(x)$ is a $G_\delta$. For $q\in\Bbb Q$ the set $H_q=\Bbb R\times\{q\}$ is closed, so

$$\left(\bigcup_{x\in C\setminus E}L(x)\right)\setminus\bigcup_{q\in\Bbb Q}H_q$$

is a $G_\delta$. This set, however, is simply $Y\setminus\bigcup_{c\in E}X_c$, so $Y$ is the union of a $G_\delta$ and an $F_\sigma$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Brian, for the "yes" answer and the nice proof, which I got stuck trying to work out for myself'. I saw that the Fan had a perfect subset, but that is as far as I could get.

Comment: @Garabed: You're very welcome.